# Can calling memset on a dynamically allocated memory cause heap corruption

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, heap-memory

While debugging a segmentation fault in a real project, where the crash happens after a long run with random testing which are not easy to reproduce. Crash point shows crash in a function which is written something like

```
void deallocateObject( objectType* ptr)
{
    ASSERT(ptr);
    if(!ptr)
        return;
    if(ptr->customDeallocator)
        ptr->customDeallocator->deallocate();
    else
        free(ptr);
}
```

There are various kind of allocator and deallocator being used in the project.
To just verify that the segmentation fault is not because of allocated memory not being set to NULL after deallocation, I added a call to memset after the last statement in this function.

```
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(objectType));
```

But after this change I started getting crash every time with message saying heap is corrupted.

So my question is how and in what scenario a call to memset() can cause heap corruption.

Comment: You call `memset(ptr...` after `free(ptr)`  ? Obviously this is undefined behaviour

Comment: Freed memory must not be touched. Use tools like Valgrind to debug memory errors instead.

Comment: After assert, why'd you check for NULL again?

Comment: @Sauav Ghosh, basically the assert which is used here is not standard C++ language assert. This is a custom assert which is disabled in release builds.

Comment: @DineshMaurya So, then it's not relevant. Either don;t show the call, or show the full implementation. __Don't confuse people, please__.

Comment: The normal assert is disabled in release builds. Well, it's disabled when you define `NDEBUG`, which nearly everybody does for a release build, anyway.

Comment: I suspect part of your problem might be that you're not sure in which language you're programming. You talk about C++ asserts, but then use C functions like `free` and `memset`. In C++, the things you're trying to do (like custom deallocators) are much better supported than in C; the Standard C++ library has direct support for them in `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is how and in what scenario a call to memset() can cause heap corruption.

Any time you use it to modify memory that might be being used to track the internal structure of the heap. For example, memory that you just told the heap allocator that you were finished with and that it was now free to use for any purpose such as, for example, tracking the internal structure of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

> *To just verify that the segmentation fault is not because of allocated memory not being set to NULL after deallocation*

Well, that's not how you debug dynamically allocated memory related problem. A pointer containing `NULL` is as invalid as a pointer which has been already passed to `free()` memory, in terms of further deallocation.

So, whether an already `free()`-d pointer is (*manually*) set to `NULL` or not, further usage (dereference) of that pointer will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you may or may not get a segmentation fault, for certain, it's just one of many side effects of having UB.

You need to use a memory debugger, like valgrind to catch and resolve the issue.

FWIW, any attempt of using invalid memory (including `NULL`, yes) invokes UB, avoid that.